# accelerated addforce for rigidbody

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, frame-rate

I need a method for accelerating the `addforce` method to the object.

Force Result feels too slow and I want it to be applied faster and for the final result time lapse shorten.

```
void FixedUpdate()
{....     
    Vector3 v_x = new Vector3(keyb_x, 0, 0);
    Vector3 force_ = v_x * kspeed * Time.deltaTime;
    float speed = rigidbody.velocity.magnitude;

    rigidbody.AddForce(force_, ForceMode.Impulse);
 ....}
```

Raising gravity from -9 to -19 or more in the y direction gives the expected result, but all other objects are affected. I want only it to apply to a specific object only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All gravity does is apply a downward force to all of your rigidbodies every physics update. For 2D unity physics you could use `rigidbody2D.GravityScale`, which scales gravity's effect on a per-rigidbody basis, but for 3D rigid bodies you should apply a constant force equal to the change in gravity you want for your object

e.g.

```
//adds a downforce of 10 per second
rigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.down * 10f * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
```

You'll want to put this in your fixed update function.

Answer (score 0):

object_Rigid2D.gravityScale += gravity_Increase * Time.deltaTime;

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy way to reach this. Consider you have an object which you move with addForce (I use impulse, other modes probably work too) by 1 unit (so vector is something like (1, 0, 0)) and object mass and drag are both 1, so the object moves properly but you want to make it quicker/slower. In that case you need to reduce it's mass and increase drag to make it quick and vice versa. For example you can make it quicker if you set mass to 2 and drag for 0.5 or slower if mass is 0.25 and drag is 4. Only rule is that drag * mass = 1.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).